# Trying to define variables from the results of a query in php

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to define variables from the results of a query, but I cannot manage to get this to work. I am trying to make my site multilangual, so I want to define a lot of text items (identifiers) that I have stored in a database. The table looks like this:

```
ID, Identifier, English, Dutch
1, Owned_by, "Owned by", "Eigendom van"
2, Owner_of, "Owner of", "Eigenaar van"
etc
etc
```

where the Column Identifier is the variable that I want to define and 1 of the 2 languages is the value that I want to give the variable. I have define a previous query from which the result is the language requested by the user, so $language_2 is the outcome from the previous query. So when $language_2 = "Dutch", I would like all the records in the table to be defined with the value in the column "Dutch".

When I use the code below the variables will be printed (echoed) but I cannot use them as an actual variable to use in my site.

```
$sql_3 = "SELECT Identifier, ".$language_2." as Language FROM translate";
$result_3 = mysql_query($sql_3) OR die (mysql_error());
while ($row_3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_3))
{
echo "$".$row_3['Identifier']." = '".$row_3['Language']."';<BR>";
}
```

How can I get them to actually become a variable that I can use in my site?

Answer (score 1):

Add brackets arround the string that is the variable name:

```
${$row_3['Identifier']} = $row_3['Language'];
```

Comment: No problem! :) Don't forget to mark this as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get an [associated array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) if you must use the older `mysql_*` functions, then use variable variables to get what you want

```
$$row_3['Identifier'] = $row_3['Language'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
${$row_3['Identifier']} = $row_3['Language'];
```